# AutoCompleteTextView is not going to the next EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I tried **singleLine=true** , **imeoption=ActionNext** also **nextfocusdown**.

but autocompleteTextView is not going to next EditText.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/at_quality"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_border"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter Quality"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_design"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_design"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_border"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Design"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

so i want a solution in order to go to the above AutocompleteTextView to EditText on android softkey enter is clicked.